# Connecting Sixteen Shades

Tags: visual, connect-wall

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #42: Wordless Connecting Walls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7045/60644)</sup>

---

[image]

> **TASK: Partition these 16 colours into 4 groups of 4 based on shared properties. Then identify the only colour (not represented here) which satisfies all 4 categories.**

Comment: And yes, you know what you need to do first of all... (at least you only need to do it 16 times...!)

Comment: (oh, it has started already :0 )

Comment: to save people effort, the decimal codes are '210 105 30', '148 0 211', '46 139 87', '100 149 237', '218 165 32', '255 0 255', '154 205 50', '230 230 250', '0 255 127', '255 99 71', '0 206 209', '216 191 216', '173 255 47', '255 160 122', '0 139 139', '139 0 0', so the hexadecimal codes are D2-69-1E, 94-0-D3, 2E-8B-57, 64-95-ED, DA-A5-20, FF-0-FF, 9A-CD-32, E6-E6-FA, 0-FF-7F, FF-63-47, 0-CE-D1, D8-BF-D8, AD-FF-2F, FF-A0-7A, 0-8B-8B, 8B-0-0 Note, I have no idea whether either of those is relevant, but I'm guessing one might be, and figured might as well save people 'manual' labor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you have the colours from left to right, top to bottom:

> Chocolate, Dark violet, Sea green, Cornflower blue;
>  Goldenrod, Fuchsia, Yellow green, Lavender;
>  Spring green, Tomato, Dark turquoise, Thistle;
>  Green yellow, Light salmon, Dark cyan and Dark red.

Groups are:

> Dark: Dark violet, Dark turquoise, Dark cyan, Dark red.

> Green: Sea green, Green yellow, Spring green, Yellow green.

> Food: Chocolate, Light salmon, Tomato, Cornflower.

> Plants: Thistle, Lavender, Goldenrod, Fuchsia.

Final answer is:

> DARK OLIVE GREEN #556b2f
>  [image]

Title:

> 16 is a reference to Hexadecimals! *OP edit for completeness:* And the initials of the words in the puzzle title spell CSS, which also stands for [Cascading Style Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS), a style sheet language used to control the presentation of web pages and which supports the use of all the [colour names](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) in this puzzle.

Comment: You're *very* close...! 'Magenta' goes by another name which is probably more obviously appropriate for this category (which does not need to be as specific as 'FLOWERS'). And your final answer (despite its seasonal relevance) does not match the patterns exhibited by all of the other groups. (Use the title!)

Comment: How about now...

Comment: That's the name for FF00FF that fits best (though you need to correct it in your list too). If you consult the right list of options you will see there is only one possible correct answer here. Don't forget to use the title! (Hint: You should be able to solve this puzzle using any internet browser...)

Comment: This must be it!

Comment: Stiv I changed the final answer it is in this site: www.rapidtables.com

Comment: Bingo! Well done :) Checkmark to follow

Comment: I have a puzzle for you next, but I need to perfect it.

Comment: Sounds good. Any chance you can explain the choice of title here please? (I worked off [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp) and the premise "All modern browsers support the following 140 color names" to ensure this correct solution could be reached regardless of software choice...)

Comment: Er... not quite right on the title there... Recheck those initials!

Comment: Sorry I went on dumb mode there, how now its right

Comment: You're pretty much on it but it could be clearer. I'll make a tiny edit, which you're welcome to roll back of course... Well done again :)